# Present Simple vs Present Continuous in "It happens because ice ____ (FLOAT) into the Atlantic Ocean."

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

I've come across a grammar task for English Exam preparation.
There goes a text:

> *A survey by the Japan Agency for Science and Technology shows that Arctic ice **is melting** (**Present Continuous is used to stress changes happening around now, as far as I understand**) at a far quicker rate than anticipated.*
>
> *... Now there is also less sea ice in the Arctic Ocean. It happens because ice ___________ (FLOAT) into the Atlantic Ocean.*

Can I use Present Continuous in that gap to show that the state of floating ice is not typical for the region so I could imply the changes happening around now? Or is it better to use Present Simple to imply that the fact is true in general?

Comment: You understand the difference quite clearly -- the problem is that there's not enough context here to decide which set of facts the author wants to emphasize. Either form could be relevant. That makes this a bad exam question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it is describing the current, ongoing movement or activity of the ice, I would say it's more natural to say

> ... Now there is also less sea ice in the Arctic Ocean. It happens because ice *is floating* into the Atlantic Ocean.

You'd only use *floats* (simple present tense) in this context to express general truths, repeated actions or unchanging situations. e.g. `ice floats on water` is true anytime, anywhere.

In the context of arctic ice, it not necessarily a given that arctic ice *must* float *into* the Atlantic Ocean. Seasonal or even cyclical weather phenomena (e.g. *El Niño* or *La Niña*) could possibly affect this and they could just stay put in the Arctic for example.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I suggested Present Simple because it is given as a correct answer along with Present Perfect.

Comment: You're most welcome!