# Help me, please, to choose between Perfect and Continuous

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, present-tense

Here's the end of the text presented in a [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/211338/present-simple-vs-present-continuous-in-it-happens-because-ice-float-int) I posted previously.

> The coastal ice in parts of Canada and Alaska has become quite
>   brittle. Ice easily breaks away in large pieces and melts in the open ocean. Now there is also less sea ice in the Arctic Ocean. It happens because ice is floating  into the Atlantic Ocean.
>
> Scientists say that the lack of ice represents clear proof that the planet **___________ (WARM)**. Back in the past it could take three years to get through the waterway's thick ice successfully, now – just a few weeks.

I reckon, Present Continuous and Present Perfect are both possible there. However, I wonder if there is enough context to eliminate one of my choices and have the only one left?

Comment: Good question! I’ve never thought about the subtle differences.

Answer (score 1):

Present perfect would be:

> Scientists say that the lack of ice represents clear proof that the planet **has warmed**.

Present continuous would be:

> Scientists say that the lack of ice represents clear proof that the planet **is warming**.

Both would be correct; the planet **has warmed** and **is warming**. However, present continuous seems more correct to me, because the present perfect usage (**has warmed**) could imply that the planet warmed for a time, and has stopped warming.

While present continuous could imply that the planet wasn’t warming before but now is — that it **has warmed**; has finished warm*ing* — it is slightly less likely to create that connotation; I’d go with present perfect.

Hope that helps!